# "Add More" button for generating dynamic form inputs using ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I implement Add More form inputs kind of function using ionic framework and angularjs?

Should be like this -

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove-bs3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define an array with inputs, and loop through them to display:

```
$scope.inputs = [
    { value: null }
];

$scope.addInput = function () {
    $scope.inputs.push({ value: null });
}

$scope.removeInput = function (index) {
    $scope.inputs.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="input.value" />
    <button ng-if="$index == inputs.length - 1" 
            ng-click="addInput()">+</button>
    <button ng-if="$index != inputs.length - 1"
            ng-click="removeInput($index)">-</button>
</div>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjdxz6zp/3/)

Comment: devqon - Thanks for prompt help. Would you mind if you help me with a plunker or jsfiddle for this? It will help me a lot. Please see, I am totally new to it and have least idea on UI level

Comment: Oh - I cant use bootstrap and jquery because I am using Ionic Framework, thats why I am stuck :( do you how to do it with Ionic?

Comment: This is made without using bootstrap and jquery, pure angular so it will also work in ionic. The bootstrap and jquery links aren't needed

Comment: Thanks, can you also please help me with how to take the values entered in these dynamic fields to the controller.js. i tried but failing :(. I am trying to enter as many number of inputs by clicking + and when click on one button say search, it takes all values entered in those input fields to controller in an array. Can you please help with it !!! I will highly thankful .