# Ionic 2 Dynamic form input

Tags: angular, ionic2

the answer is already on this question: ["Add More" button for generating dynamic form inputs using ionic framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579909/add-more-button-for-generating-dynamic-form-inputs-using-ionic-framework) for ionic 1 but am looking for a solution for Ionic 2 I did manage to make it work but the minus button appears for the very first input.

Comment: what is that you have tried in ionic2? add update your code with the post. Before raising a question, suggesst you to see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're creating these dynamic items with an array on your .ts file why don't you add an *ngIf to the element you wish to hide on the first instance? Would something like this work?

```
<div *ngFor="let number of items; let $i = index">
  <!-- content here-->
  <button
    class="button"
    *ngIf="!$i = 1"
    ion-button
    clear
    large
    (click)="remove();">
  </button>
</div>
```

if not you could do an ngStyle and apply a display: none the same way or just modify your styles to not include the first button.

```
.button:first-of-type { display: none }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the other way you can do this as do it also

First Make an Array for dynamic input count ..

for example ..

```
myinputs = [];
```

then

prepare your template like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myinputs">
<ion-input  [(ngModel)]="item">
</div>
<button ion-button (tap)="addinput()">add input</button>
<button ion-button (tap)="result()">result</button>
```

now to add a little bit addinput action

```
addinput(){
// for now you can push empty string
this.myinputs.push("")
}
/// you can simply console out to see the result  
result(){
  console.log('result',this.myinputs)
}
```